# Deserialize Xml Using Same Object With root element and child element

Tags: sql, xml-serialization, deserialization, c#-3.0

I have a scenario where the root element and child element has same attribute, due to this i am facing issue on retrieving the value.

**Sample XML**

```
<entry>
<building id='12345asdf'>
<home/>
<constructiondate id='6789jklh'></constructiondate>
<yearbuilt id='4569uiop'></yearbuilt>
</building>
</entry>
```

I am trying to deserialize the above Sample XML to the class object building.

```
[XmlType("building")]
public class Building
{
[XmlAttribute("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
public string home{get; set; }
public string constructiondate {get; set; }
public string yearbuilt {get; set; }
}
```

But, after deserialization the value id always pointing to **'4569uiop'** last value of id attribute in the xml node.

**Expected value:**
The value should always retrieve it from the building id attribute.
**id=12345asdf.**

Please help & Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to changes class structure ?

Comment: I think yes.. so that we can access only the id that belongs to building